# Sum row values and create new category

Tags: r, sum, aggregation

I'm working with a population dataframe and I have information for different years and age groups divided by bins of five years. Once I filtered the information for the location I'm interested in I have this:

```
Location    age group   total90  total95  total00  total05  total10
  A          0 to 4      10428    118902     76758   967938   205472
  A          5 to 9      18530    238928    260331   277635   303180    
  A         10 to 14    180428    208902    226758   267938   305472
  A         15 to 19    185003    332089    242267   261793   135472
```

Now what I want is to create new age groups to have something like this:

```
Location    age group       total90  total95    total00  total05    total10
  A          5 to 14        198958   447830     487089    545573    608652
  A           other         195431   450991     319025   1229731    340944
```

where

age group "5 to 14" is the total of "5 to 9" + "10 to 14" for each year &

"other"   is the total of "0 to 4" + "15 to 19" for each year

I tried selecting the columns with numbers so I could add the totals for each age group and create a row with the new age group but I can't add rows in an easy way and I'm complicating things more. I'm sure there is an easy way to solve this but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to alter your dummy data slightly (juste removed some space to make reading from plain text easy)to make it work without further manipulation

```
df <- data.table::fread("Location    age_group   total90  total95  total00  total05  total10
  A          0_to_4      10428    118902     76758   967938   205472
  A          5_to_9      18530    238928    260331   277635   303180    
  A         10_to_14    180428    208902    226758   267938   305472
  A         15_to_19    185003    332089    242267   261793   135472")

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
    # alter the character variable age_group reducing problem to one ifelse clause
    dplyr::mutate(age_group = ifelse(age_group == "5_to_9" | age_group == "10_to_14", "5_to_14", "other")) %>%
    # build grouping (I included Location but possibly your need is diferent)
    dplyr::group_by(Location, age_group) %>%
    # sum in one call all not grouped columns (therefore you have to remove Location in case you do not want it in the grouping
    dplyr::summarize(across(everything(), ~sum(.x))) %>%
    # ungrouping prevents unwanted behaviour down stream
    dplyr::ungroup()

# A tibble: 2 x 7
  Location age_group total90 total95 total00 total05 total10
  <chr>    <chr>       <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
1 A        5_to_14    198958  447830  487089  545573  608652
2 A        other      195431  450991  319025 1229731  340944
```

Answer (score 0):

See my answer below:

My first line reads in the data shown.

```
library(tidyverse)

#read in data
my_data <- read_csv("pop_data.csv")

#add extra tags
my_data1 <- my_data %>%
  mutate(Category = c("other","5 to 14","5 to 14","other")) %>%
  select(-`age group`)

#find numeric columns
numeric_col <- unlist(lapply(my_data1, is.numeric))  

#combine the data
my_data2 <- aggregate(my_data1[,numeric_col],
          by = list(my_data1$Location, my_data1$Category),
          FUN = sum) 

#rename first 2 columns
colnames(my_data2)[1:2] <- c("Location", "age group")
```

And the result:

```
  Location age group total90 total95 total00 total05 total10
1        A   5 to 14  198958  447830  487089  545573  608652
2        A     other  195431  450991  319025 1229731  340944
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with **dplyr**

You can first `mutate`the `age group` column into the ranges of interest, then `summarise` `across` the columns of interest, with the `sum` function

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(`age group` = ifelse(`age group` %in% c(`5 to 9`, `10 to 14`), `5 to 14`, 'other') %>%
       group_by(`age group`, location) %>% 
       summarise(across(total90:total10), sum))%>%
       ungroup()
```

Comment: I tried this one but I get a message error  " Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `age group`.
ℹ `age group = `%>%`(...)`.
x no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "character"

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness - in case you ever want to change your target start/end ages, here's a way to parameterize `target_start` and `target_end`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

target_start <- 5
target_end <- 14

df %>% 
  separate(`age group`, into = c("grp_start", "grp_end"), sep = " to ") %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("grp"), as.numeric),
         age_group = 
           if_else(grp_start >= target_start & grp_end <= target_end,
                   glue::glue("{target_start} to {target_end}"), 
                   "other")
         ) %>% 
  group_by(age_group, Location) %>% 
  summarise(across(total90:total10, sum)) %>%
  ungroup()
```